# iOS - Cannot deep link into official Facebook client ("The page you requested was not found")

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've followed other questions on this however, What seems to work for them doesn't seem to work for me. I tried putting in the hard value directly into the facebookURL variable, still I get the same result. It opens the facebook app, and gives the message "The page you requested was not found".

```
     NSDictionary *profile = [PFuserProfile objectForKey:@"profile"];

NSString *facebookId = [profile objectForKey:@"facebookId"];

NSMutableString *fullText = [NSMutableString string];

[fullText appendString:@"fb://profile/"];
[fullText appendString:facebookId];

NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullText];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookURL]) {
    NSLog(fullText);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
} else {
    NSMutableString *fullText2 = [NSMutableString string];
    [fullText2 appendString: @"http://facebook.com/"];
    [fullText2 appendString:facebookId];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullText2]];
}
```

the second option, if the app isn't installed, works perfectly.

Comment: What is full text when you log it?